# Average of array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, average

I have an array of objects that contains the name and marks of students. like below

I need to calculate the 'average' marks each student has and compare the 'average' marks to get the top student. I am trying like below, I am not getting what am I missing?

```js
var Students = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    marks: [78,80,89,90,68]
  },
  {
    name: "Alin",
    marks: [87,60,59,70,68]
  },
  {
    name: "bikash",
    marks: [82,60,79,60,80]
  }
];


for (let i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
  var average = Students[i].reduce((total, next)=> total + next.marks) /2 
}

console.log(average)
```

I need to have average marks of each students to compare the results of All students

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for traditional loop:

```
const Students = [{
    name: 'Bob',
    marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68],
},
    {
        name: 'Alin',
        marks: [87, 60, 59, 70, 68],
    },
    {
        name: 'bikash',
        marks: [82, 60, 79, 60, 80],
    },
];

var average;
for (let i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
    var marks = Students[i]["marks"];
    var total = 0;
    console.log(marks);
    for (var j = 0; j < marks.length; j++ ) {
        total += marks[j];
    }
    average = total / marks.length;

    // answer for question in the comment
    var msg = Students[i]["name"] + " has average mark: " + average;
    console.log(msg)

}

console.log(average)
```

Comment: hi, thanks. I wanted it in the traditional way. How can I console.log as for example "Alin has average .. and Bob had average .. "  like printing the average numbers for each student?

Comment: @Sal you just need to print inside loop, or append to the variable like ```var msg = Students[i]["name"] + " has average mark: " + average;```

Comment: @Sal I have updated my answer there you can see how I have printed it in the cansole

Comment: Hi Doston, thanks for your time. I want to add the average numbers to the object so that it becomes [{name:"Bob", average : 89}, {name:"alin", average : 87}], and sort the array so that I can have who got the highest average number. if Alin and Bob both got same number I need to compare that too. can you please guide me further?

Comment: @Sal you are welcome, I think you should accept my answer as accept if your problem is resolved. For your next question, please create new question and we will work on that

Comment: accepted :) I am creating a new question and sending you the link

Comment: here is the link to the new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320231/insert-new-element-in-an-array-of-object-and-sort-the-array

Comment: @Sal thanks for accepting, I have posted my answer for your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64321145/7186690  Please, let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this:

```js
const students = [{
    name: 'Bob',
    marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68],
  },
  {
    name: 'Alin',
    marks: [87, 60, 59, 70, 68],
  },
  {
    name: 'bikash',
    marks: [82, 60, 79, 60, 80],
  },
];

const topStudent = students
  .map(student => ({
    ...student,
    averageMark: student.marks.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / student.marks.length,
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.averageMark - b.averageMark)
  .pop();

console.log(topStudent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. It returns you an array of objects with the name and the average score of the students.

Its also sorted from highest average to lowest

```js
let arr = [
    {
        name: "Bob",
        marks: [78,80,89,90,68]
    },

    {
        name: "Alin",
        marks: [87,60,59,70,68]
    },

    {
        name: "bikash",
        marks: [82,60,79,60,80]
    }
]

let averages = arr.map(({ marks, name }) => {
   let average = marks.reduce((a,v) => a + v) / marks.length
   return { name , average }
}).sort((a,b) => b.average - a.average);

let [{ name }] = averages;

console.log(averages)
console.log("top student: ", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `reduce` the `marks` array of each `Student`, not a `Student` object, as this is not an array.

`next` is the next value in the array, not the next item in `Students`.

Finally, place the `console.log` line inside the loop so to get all the results printed out.

```js
var Students = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    marks: [78,80,89,90,68]
  },
  {
    name: "Alin",
    marks: [87,60,59,70,68]
  },
  {
    name: "bikash",
    marks: [82,60,79,60,80]
  }
];


for (let i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
    var average = Students[i].marks.reduce((total, next)=> total + next) / Students[i].marks.length;
    console.log(average);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract it in a function:

```js
var Students = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    marks: [78,80,89,90,68]
  },
  {
    name: "Alin",
    marks: [87,60,59,70,68]
  },
  {
    name: "bikash",
    marks: [82,60,79,60,80]
  }
];

// Student avarage
var averages = []
for (let i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
  var avg = average(Students[i].marks);
  console.log(Students[i].name + ": " + avg)
  averages.push(avg)
}

// Total average
console.log("total average: " + average(averages))

function average(array) {
  return array.reduce((total, mark) => total + mark, 0) / array.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the ways of finding the student with maximum average using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var Students = [{name:"Alin",marks:[87,60,59,70,68]},{name:"Bob",marks:[78,80,89,90,68]},{name:"bikash",marks:[82,60,79,60,80]}];

const getTopStudent = (students) => {
//Find the avg of the current student
  const formattedStudents = students.map(student => ({...student, avg: student.marks.reduce((t, m) => t+m, 0)/student.marks.length}))
  return formattedStudents.reduce((res, student) => {
      //Check if the avg of the student in res object is less than the avg of the current student, then return current student.
    if((res.avg || 0) < student.avg){
      return {
        ...student
      }
    }
    return res;
  }, {})
}

console.log(getTopStudent(Students))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note: In the above example I have not considered if there are more than one student having the same avg.

Below is the example which will return all the students if the average is same

```js
var Students = [{name:"Alin",marks:[87,60,59,70,68]},{name:"Bob",marks:[78,80,89,90,68]},{name:"bikash",marks:[82,60,79,60,80]},{name:"Joey",marks:[78,80,84,90,73]}];

const getTopStudent = (students) => {
  const formattedStudents = students.map(student => ({ ...student,
    avg: student.marks.reduce((t, m) => t + m, 0) / student.marks.length
  }))
  const finalRes = formattedStudents.reduce((res, student) => {
  //if the res.avg is less than current student avg then update the res object with the new avg and the students
    if ((res.avg || 0) < student.avg) {
      return {
        avg: student.avg,
        students: [{ ...student }]
      }
    } else if ((res.avg || 0) === student.avg) {
    //If average of the current student is same as res.avg, then push the current student to the res.students
      res.students.push(student);
      return res;
    }
    return res;
  }, {});

  return finalRes.students;
}

//More than one student with max avg
console.log(getTopStudent(Students));

//One student with max avg
console.log(getTopStudent(Students.slice(0,3)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```