# Insert new element in an array of object and sort the array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that contains the name and marks of students. like below

How can I calculate the 'average' marks each student has and compare the 'average' marks to get the top student. I don’t want to use ES6

```js
var Students = [{
    name: "Bob",
    marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "Alin",
    marks: [87, 60, 59, 70, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "bikash",
    marks: [82, 60, 79, 60, 80]
  }
];


var average;
var newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Students.length; i++) {
  var marks = Students[i]["marks"];
  var total = 0;
  console.log(marks);
  for (var j = 0; j < marks.length; j++) {
    total += marks[j];
  }
  average = total / marks.length;
  newArray.push(average)
  var msg = Students[i]["name"] + " has average mark: " + average;
  console.log(msg)

}

console.log(newArray)
```

I want to insert the average numbers in an object along with the names like
[{name: "Bob", average:89.4},{name: "Alin", average:87.2},{name: "Bikash", average:89.4} ]
and sort the object.

Finally, I want to have console.log as Bob is the Top student
OR
Alin and Bob are the brightest students (in case both of them have the same average number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't push the average into a new array, add it as a property of `Students[i]` with `Students[i].average = average;`.

Then you can sort the array using that property, and print the to students from the sorted array.

```js
var Students = [{
    name: "Bob",
    marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "Alin",
    marks: [87, 60, 59, 70, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "bikash",
    marks: [82, 60, 79, 60, 80]
  }
];


var average;
for (let i = 0; i < Students.length; i++) {
  var marks = Students[i]["marks"];
  var total = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < marks.length; j++) {
    total += marks[j];
  }
  average = total / marks.length;
  Students[i].average = average;
  var msg = Students[i]["name"] + " has average mark: " + average;
  console.log(msg)

}
Students.sort((s1, s2) => s2.average - s1.average);
var topAvg = Students[0].average;
var topStudents = Students.filter(s => s.average == topAvg).map(s => s.name).join(", ");
console.log(`Top Students are ${topStudents} with mark ${topAvg}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used non ES6 functins, instead traditional for loop and other. Please, find answers for your three questions:

- Creating a list/array of object in this format: [ { name: 'Alin', average: 68.8 }, ..]
- Sorting a list/array with average value
- Getting students with the highest average grade.

  ```
       const Students = [{
       name: 'Bob',
       marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68],
   },
       {
           name: 'Alin',
           marks: [87, 60, 59, 70, 68],
       },
       {
           name: 'bikash',
           marks: [82, 60, 79, 60, 80],
       },
       {
           name: 'Doston',
           marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68],
       },
   ];

   var average;
   var data = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
       var marks = Students[i]["marks"];
       var total = 0;
       console.log(marks);
       for (var j = 0; j < marks.length; j++ ) {
           total += marks[j];
       }
       average = total / marks.length;

       var msg = Students[i]["name"] + " has average mark: " + average;
       console.log(msg);

       // Answer for the first question:
       var item = {"name": Students[i]["name"], "average": average};
       data.push(item);

   }

   function compareAndSort(a,b) {
       return parseInt(a.average, 10) - parseInt(b.average, 10);
   }

   data.sort(compareAndSort);

   // Answer for the second question: sort [ { name: 'Alin', average: 68.8 }, ..]
   console.log(data);

   // Answer for the third question - getting students who has highest mark is last since it is sorted
   var bestStudent = data[data.length - 1];
   console.log(bestStudent.name + " has got the highest mark: " + bestStudent.average);

   var bestStudents = [bestStudent];

   // check if there is only one person with this highest mark
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
       if (data[i].average >= bestStudent.average && data[i].name !== bestStudent.name) {
           bestStudents.push(data[i]);
       }
   }

   // all best students
   console.log(bestStudents);
  ```

I have added some data to the JSON input, so that you get two best students

Comment: `const` and `let` are ES6. Use `var` instead.

Comment: @ElectricShadow oh yeah, thanks for correcting me. I am used to working with ```const``` and ```let``` :) and forgot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loops, I used the built-in array methods, which tend to be much more readable (although they would be a lot more readable if you used ES6 syntax).

I use the `Array.prototype.map` method to convert the list of marks into the average. In order to find this average, I use `Array.prototype.reduce` to add up all of the values, and then I divide by the length of the marks array. I then sort the array using `Array.prototype.sort`.

In order to get the top students, I use `Array.prototype.filter` in order to select only the students will average marks equal to the top average mark, which since the `averages` array is sorted, will be `averages[0].average`.

```js
var Students = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "Alin",
    marks: [87, 60, 59, 70, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "bikash",
    marks: [82, 60, 79, 60, 80]
  }
];

var averages = Students.map(function(student) {
  return {
    name: student.name,
    average: student.marks.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }) / student.marks.length
  };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.average - a.average;
});

var top_students = averages.filter(function(student, _i, arr) {
  return student.average === arr[0].average;
});

console.log("Averages:");
console.log(averages);

console.log("Top Students:\n");
console.log(top_students);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional array. In theory, calling `sort` is less efficient than to gather the best student(s) during your loop.

So:

```js
var students = [{name: "Bob",marks: [78,80,89,90,68] },{name: "Alin",marks: [87,60,59,70,68]},{name: "bikash",marks: [82,60,79,60,80]}];

var topAverage = -1; 
var topStudents = [];
var newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
    var marks = students[i].marks;
    var total = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < marks.length; j++ ) {
        total += marks[j];
    }
    var average = total / marks.length;
    // Keep topAverage & topStudents up to date:
    if (average >= topAverage) {
        if (average > topAverage) {
            topStudents.length = 0; // clear previous content
            topAverage = average;
        }
        topStudents.push(students[i].name);
    }
}

console.log("Top student(s): " + topStudents + " with an average of " + topAverage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Students = [{
    name: "Bob",
    marks: [78, 80, 89, 90, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "Alin",
    marks: [87, 60, 59, 70, 68]
  },
  {
    name: "bikash",
    marks: [82, 60, 79, 60, 80]
  }
];

console.log (
  Students.map (
    student => (
      {
        name: student.name,
        average:
          student.marks.reduce ((a, m) => a + m, 0) /
          student.marks.length
      }
    )
  ).sort ((a, b) => b.average - a.average)
);
```

Comment: OP said not to use ES6 syntax.